# Issue with conversion of Map inside a Map into JSON in Java

Tags: java, javascript, json, hashmap, jackson

I have a treemap in Java which has structure like this below:

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> testMap = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

public String getTestMapInJson(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> testMap){
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String testMapInJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(testMap);
return testMapInJson;
}
```

Now, when I am trying to convert this map in JSON using Jackson API(snippet above), I am getting data like this and I want to populate this data in HTML tables.

```
[
{
    "key": "1.1.1.1",
    "value": {
        "string1": 500,
        "string2": 400
    }
},
{
    "key": "2.2.2.2",
    "value": {
        "string1": 500,
        "string2": 400
    }
}
]
```

HTML table output is like:

```
IP Address  Value
1.1.1.1     [object Object]
2.2.2.2     [object Object]
```

I want it like this:

```
IP Address  Value
1.1.1.1     String1 count1
            String2 count2
2.2.2.2     String1 count1
            String2 count2
```

The internal hashmap doesn't get converted exactly into JSON format. I want something so that the internal hashmap too gets converted into similar map like the outer map. 
It's feasible for me to make changes on any side (client/server). What should I do?

Comment: What you desire in the table attribute in value column. please prove a sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resp = [
{
    "ip": "1.1.1.1",
    "data": {
        "string1": 500,
        "string2": 400
    }
},
{
    "ip": "2.2.2.2",
    "data": {
        "string1": 500,
        "string2": 400
    }
}
]
```

**To access the Object:**

```
for(var obj : resp) {
     $.each(obj, function(key,value){
         alert(key + "==" + value);
         if(key == "data") {
            $.each(value, function(innerKey, innerVal) {
               alert(innerKey + "===" + innerVal);
            });
         }
     });
}
```

**To design table:**

```
var table = $("<table>");
//header
var header = $("<tr>").append($("<th>").text("IP Address")).append($("<th>").text("Value"));

for(var obj : resp) {
    $.each(obj, function(key,value){
        var isFirst = true;
        if(key == "data") {
            $.each(value, function(innerKey, innerVal) {
              var tr;
              if(isFirst) {
                  // ip address and value
                  tr = $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text(value)).append($("<td>").text(innerKey + " " + innerValue));
                  isFirst = false;
              } else {
                  // blank and value
                  tr = $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text("")).append($("<td>").text(innerKey + " " + innerValue));
              }
              table.append(tr);
            });
         }
    });
}
```